# Access to a sub-property in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, response

on Laravel I have an answer for this from a query:

```
{
"id": 19,
"skin_id": 13,
"skin_payment_provider_id": 16,
"payment_method_id": 24,
"rank": 1,
"is_visible": 1,
"is_enabled": 1,
"created_at": "2020-07-16T10:09:51.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2020-07-16T10:09:51.000000Z",
"deleted_at": null,
"laravel_through_key": 13,
"payment_provider": {
    "id": 5,
    "parent_id": null,
    "name": "Paypal",
    "slug": "paypal",
    "thumb": null,
    "is_enabled": true,
    "options": null,
    "percentage": null,
    "rank": 1,
    "created_at": "2020-07-16T08:47:49.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-07-16T08:47:49.000000Z",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "laravel_through_key": 16
}
```

}

I can access the properties without problems such as:

$result->payment_method_id or $result->skin_id etc but I can't access the property $result->payment_provider!

if I call a return $result I see the answer I put above but if I call $result->payment_provider I have an empty answer.
I tried to call through Arr::get() but it is always the same...
What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Show proper, _exact_ example code of what you are doing, instead of giving us these vague verbal descriptions. _“but if I call $result->payment_provider”_ - what is “call” supposed to mean? What context did you try to use it in?

Comment: I'm using it inside a controller, the strange thing is that all the results are visible but I can't access the payment_provider property

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you convert the json to an array..

i guess your payment provider is converted as an array an not an object

```php
$result->payment_provider['id']; or $result['payment_provider']['id']
```

Dumping it like dd($result)
or print_r($result)

Will help you understand whats in your var.

Comment: Yes, I tried but the answer is: "message": "Trying to access array offset on value of type null".
If I try with $ result['payment_provider'] the answer is empty

Comment: I can't try a dd () because it's a call to a microservice with double authentication, I'm making calls with postman

Comment: as others suggested, show us, how your example above, becomes a php variable.

This actually suggests it's value is NULL..

Comment: if you can't use dd, try Log::error(print_r($var, true)); and check your logfile.
or consider using laravel telescope, or Xdebug

Comment: with print_r($response) I have the same response

Comment: Share where $result is assigned.. without it's quite hard to help you further.

Comment: Taking another look at your code, it looks like you are using a laravel model, instead of an input result.., Where payment provider is a relation, which you have to load() or with() in the query....Therefore show us the entire controller method

Comment: If I turn the model response into a collection then I can log in.
$collect = collect($result):
return $collect['payment_provider'] ['id'] <- works